# Resize circle button with dragging like in designer window

Tags: wpf, button, resize, geometry, ellipse

I have a circular button, which I want to resize (similarly to how you do it in the design window). If this was a rectangle I can attach some thumbs or adorners around the edges and keep track of the drag delta and update the size correspondingly. But how do I do it for a circle, I guess I could add a circular thumb around the outside and when the user drags it I can update the size of the templated parent. Any other way to go about this?

Comment: Do you want some feedback on your idea (yes, I think it's a good idea) or do you want someone to write your source code for you?

Comment: @Heinzi no, just ideas, is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: I don't know any, but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: You can use a standard rectangular resize adorner - which can be found in many places, it'll support for both ellipses and circles - does it not suit you by some reason?

Comment: @Dmitry I didn't know that it existed, i'll google it.

Comment: @Dmitry it doesn't exist as its own control, I have to implement it, inheriting from adorner correct?

Comment: Here's the one, I didn't try it myself though: http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/the-wpf-resizing-adorner-for-canvas/

Comment: @Dmitry: I've tried that one before and it works, you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Dimitry i found that one too I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one, I didn't try it myself though:
http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/the-wpf-resizing-adorner-for-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

I've to admit there's one more elegant solution for the problem, it's more advanced from a technology point of view too - namely a resize behavior:

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/09/a-wpf-behavior-for-window-resize-events-in-net-35

Comment: Resize is a ulility function, so in a way it's righ to factor it up as a behavior as opposed to a user control etc.